# Fixed Bootstrap layout not acting Responsively

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a rails app which uses bootstrap and I would like to use the fixed grid layout.

My understanding of this is that the fixed layout won't stretch to the full size of the browser page but cap itself at the 940px wide mark. However, if the page is decreased in size the fixed "container" will resize to best fit the browser.

To the best of my knowledge i have followed the documentation properly, included all of the files that one should but my fixed container doesn't shrink with the browser, it remains "fixed", does anyone know why?

if anyone needs more code just ask.

The code:

Home.html.erb using 2 rows

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span8">
                <%= render template: "static_pages/winner" %>
                <%= render partial: "static_pages/social_quarter" %>
            </div>

            <div class="span4">
                <%= render partial: "static_pages/nominations_home" %>
            </div>
            </div>
```

I am using "container" to wrap the main contant of the site in

```
<div class="container">
<%= yield %>
</div>
```

I have included the following files in the app, as well as the bootstrap-responsive.css in the assets css directory and these 2 lines to load the responsive style sheet and viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Application.css

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_bootstrap
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require bootstrap 
//= require_tree .
```

Bootstrap_overides_and_css

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";

body { padding-top: 50px }

@import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";
```

The documentation states that CSS elements should be stacked and not floated, i have this div which is used on most pages, and removing the float property doesn't solve it.

```
.article-box {

    float: inherit;
    max-width: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #888;
    background-color: #ffffff;

    .large {
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 30px;
    }

    img {   
        max-width: 100%;
        align: left;
    }
}
```

html source

```
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap-responsive.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/comment.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/dropdown_toggle.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="fc+nZpTjUYkpgqZJ9wVdru1vI/9nhUceJXc6DrNWu9g=" name="csrf-token" />
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="WOjLVAdH_q5FxvYyAnjnVw-jC17kDxd6nc4NhlxdZe0" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Is the bootstrap css and other file load properly in browser ?

Comment: Hi Abhay, I've added the html source to the edit, it seems like it

Comment: It may be a typo,but in Home.html.erb I see an open "span8" tag.

Comment: only 1 div after the first span8 div? thats just to close that section whilst remaining in the row div, unless i am misunderstanding?